# What is the difference between entangled and separable states or electron spin-singlets?

Tags: entanglement

What is the difference between entangled states and separable states or electron spin-singlets?

Comment: related on physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489114/58382

Comment: You have completely changed the nature of the question, invalidating existing answers (ie mine). Generally it would be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few things going on here. However, I think the fundamental issue is the tensor product that you write in the second expression. It implies an issue of *identification*. Your second expression is effectively saying:

- there are two different positions at which I can create a fermion. Call them P1 and P2.
- create a spin-up at P1 and a spin down at P2.

This is quite a different thing from "there are two spins, one up and one down, but I cannot distinguish which is which", corresponding to your first expression.

This may need some further elaboration, but I don't want to overcomplicate it at this point, and I'll be guided by comments.

---

If you want to write B using A's description, you need to have terms that look like both $a^\dagger_{\uparrow}a^\dagger_{\downarrow}$ and $a^\dagger_{\downarrow}a^\dagger_{\uparrow}$ because you don't know which is which (that's a very vague hand-wavy description). Now, since electrons are fermions, they are antisymmetric. That shows how we have to combine those two terms:
$$
(a^\dagger_{\uparrow}a^\dagger_{\downarrow}-a^\dagger_{\downarrow}a^\dagger_{\uparrow})|0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle.
$$
Hopefully you can now see how that matches with the B description.

Comment: It's not that A is artificial. There's very real scenarios in which either is valid, it's just that those scenarios are different. If you're talking about two electrons in an orbital, you can't tell them apart, and B applies.